# Efficient way to go about acquiring game assets

Tags: assets, asset-workflow

I was thinking about buying assets, but I don't want to waste time and want to acquire assets as fast as possible, and acquire a large amount of them, because I want to make several different games from the assets (rpg, action, shooter, etc.) Also, I want to commercialize the game, so what would you recommend me doing?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. What stage is your development & design at? If you haven't locked down the art / design / feel of the game, I would recommend grey boxing over acquiring assets, but if your much further along an answer focused on that solution wouldn't really adddress your problem. Also keep in mind that requests for resources (i.e. where can I find X) type questions are not considered on-topic, so you may need to edit your question.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the hardest part of a game is making the code and the logic work. That means, no matter how much money you spend on assets, if you don't have the code nor the experience, you'd spend way too much time coding the game. I'd suggest first making a prototype of a game, and once it's in a alpha-ish state you can think about buying assets and replacing the template ones you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is on topic, but I'll try to answer anyway:
You don't *need* to pay for your game's assets; That's why things like the Unity Assets store, ue4 store etc.. exist ;)

When it comes to commercializing the game, you really want to check for your assets' licence/s (unless you created them yourself of course), because they tell you *if and how* you can use them in your game.

If the assets are not *free for commercial purposes*, you probably need to pay the artist who created them (again check their licence requirements).

If you don't want to create the assets yourself, there are a whole lot of websites that you can find with a [simple search on the web](https://www.google.it/search?q=free+game+assets&oq=free+game+assets&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4037j0j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), but for a bit of money you can pay an artist that will make *exactly* what you need, *exactly* how you want; That's the main advantage.